# Android studio Error android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line

Tags: android, xml, google-maps-api-3

Im having an execption trying to loadn my application:

```
       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #170: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:767)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508)
```

shows up when i include a fragment

```
   <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="340dp" />
```

in my another fragment what could be problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your code please! you a have a problem inflating the view.

Comment: Have you checked your imports ?